# Python: fill out a form and confirm with a button click

Tags: python, forms, button

Which do you think is the best method to fill out a form and confirm with clicking a button with Python? Do I have to use django? I want to do it in a simple way. Is there a library?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a real question.  Edit edit edit before it's too late!

Comment: Why do you think this wasn't a real question? @gahooa

Comment: "Fill out a form"?  On a web site?  On a desktop GUI Application?  At the local post office?   What do you mean by "fill out a form"?

Comment: On a website. I try to make the questions more detailed. sorry!

Comment: What does Django have to do with fetching a web page, filling in data and posting it back to a web server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)

Answer (score 3):

There are tons. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043058/scripting-http-more-effeciently) for some gory details.